# How to retrieve pdf file from firebase using kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase storage to store pdf file. I want to access firebase storage through button inside fragment.

How do I fetch the file from Firebase Storage using Kotlin and save it to the device?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
// Create a storage reference from our app
val storageRef = storage.reference

val pdfFileRef = storageRef.child("pdfs/file.pdf")

val localFile = File.createTempFile("files", "pdf")

pdfFileRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
    // Local temp file has been created
    Log.d("TAG", "File Downloaded")
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Handle any errors
    Log.d("TAG", "Something went wrong")
}
```

Make sure you change your path in the storage reference.